# How to change action bar Title

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have developed a action-bar in Android Studio, however, the action-bar displays the activity name rather than the app name along with the icons.

For example I want it to display the app-name plus the refresh, setting and User Icon. Instead it display the activity name along with refresh, setting and User Icon.

Menuactivity.java

```
public class MenuActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_user) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(this,DashboardActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MenuMain shows the application name however once run the code it displays the activity name rather than the app name, how can I rectify this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. The easiest way is:**

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.strind.app_name);
```

**2. You can also use a custom `Toolbar` layout**

Change your existing code us

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

To like this:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_main;
```

Follow please these my tutorial to see how to implement it.

> Here's my solution - create a TextDrawable logo using custom toolbar
>
> 1. Create a custom layout with name `action_bar.xml`
> 2. Put into it this code
>
>    ```
>    <ImageView
>        android:id="@+id/image_view"
>        android:layout_width="32dp"
>        android:layout_height="32dp"
>        tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
>
>    <TextView
>        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
>        android:text="@string/app_name">   //THIS GUY 
>        android:textColor="#ffffff"
>        android:textSize="24sp"
>        android:textAlignment="gravity"
>        android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
>    ```
> 3. Add to your `onCreate` method in `MainActivity` class this code:
>
>    ```
>    //SET A DRAWABLE TO IMAGEVIEW
>    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
>    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
>    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
>    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_main);
>
>    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
>            .buildRound("A", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
>    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
>    imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
>    ```
> 4. After changes it should look like:
>
> [image]

NOTICE: To show appName i used `TextView` with `android:text="@string/app_name"` value.

Hope it help

Comment: I have tried this method, however it does not work. getActionBar().setTitle("Title"); . Yours does not work as well.

Comment: I've edited my post. Please check it as you see to show your app name, you can use `TextView`, which takes you a BIG advantages called customization,

Comment: So don't put `ImageView` and in `MainActivity` avoid code with `TextDrawable` and `ImageView`. Did you noticed that I cited already done by me post. Treat that as kind of inspiration, which works ;-)

Comment: please add `EDIT` section to your post and add your actual code I will check it

Comment: I have fixed it now just changed the activity label in android manifest file. I would like to thank you for your help. I changed the label to the app name, therefore it now display the app name instead of the activity name.